# SwiftUI - How to prevent VoiceOver from reading Form's header as "heading"

Tags: swift, swiftui, accessibility, voiceover

SwiftUI. Form with Section and header.

**How to prevent VoiceOver from reading header as "heading"?**

Here is a simple code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section(content: {
                Text("Content")
            }, header: {
                // I don't want VoiceOver to read this as "heading"
                Text("Not a heading")
                .accessibilityRemoveTraits(.isHeader) // doesn't work
            }
            )
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Currently when I turn VoiceOver ON and read elements on the screen, I hear: "Not a heading - heading". What I want to hear is: "Not a heading".

I have tried to put .accessibilityRemoveTraits(.isHeader) modifier to every place known to mankind. It didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it does not work? From where are you testing VoiceOver? I tried  your code, using the `Accessibility Inspector` native macOS app and I can [see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/je0iA.png) it only reads "Not a heading".

Comment: I’m sure. Accessibility Inspector shows text “Not a heading” and Type “heading”. And I’ve tested VoiceOver on my iPhone and it reads “Not a heading - heading”. You can try VoiceOver. It’s in Accessibility settings. I’ve set a shortcut to turn it ON and OFF with 3x Power Button.

Comment: that is a nice trick yeah, I have also the 3x shortcut set on my phone, but if it works in a11y inspector, should work on my phone too, can test it out for you. EDIT: you are right, on a physical phone it does not work, mmm weird

Comment: I think that .isHeading trait is automatically added to Section header and I don’t know how to remove or ignore it. I’ve tried hiding accessibility for header and making it visible for separate element, but I still cannot make it work as well.

Comment: @mallow did you ever figure this out?